# Would it be odd to refer to English-style tea as お茶?

Tags: word-choice, words

If I were drinking English-style black tea, made by first placing a teabag in the cup, adding sugar, pouring boiling water on to it, stirring, adding milk, and stirring again, and a friend asked me, 「何飲んでる？」, would it be odd to reply, 「お茶だよ」? Would another term like ミルクティー be more appropriate?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Black tea is usually referred to as [紅茶]{こうちゃ}.

> a friend asked me, 「何飲んでる？」, would it be odd to reply, 「お茶だよ」?

お茶 might be understood as Japanese tea (like, 麦茶{むぎちゃ} or 煎茶{せんちゃ}).

> Would another term like ミルクティー be more appropriate?

Yes, ミルクティー is also common. So I'd recommend using 紅茶 or ミルクティー to avoid any confusion.

(That said, you'd still say 「お茶しない？」「一緒{いっしょ}にお茶でもどう？」 etc. to invite someone out for tea or coffee... here you don't mean you're gonna drink Japanese tea at a cafe.)

Comment: About your PS., that's the same in English. If someone asks you out for coffee, it's not required, or even expected, to actually order a _coffee_ when you get to the cafe. That being said, not ordering _anything_ will be considered somewhat strange.

Comment: [Relevant example](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%A2%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB%E3%82%B0%E3%83%AC%E3%82%A4)

Comment: Say 午後ティー as a joke.